# why matplotlib 'key_press_event' is so slow

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, keypress

I have made a program wih tkinter that plots some waveforms using matplotlib. Then i made it interactive (pressing buttons) using Matplotlib 'key_press_event'. So every time i press the keyboard key, 'd' it moves to the right and when i press the 'a' it moves to the left. The problem is that it is too slow..i press it and the waveform moves after 1-2 seconds. The function is:

[image]

```
def keyboardpress(self, event):
   print('start')
   #i have 3 axes so with whichax i find the ax that the cursor is in 
   whichax = event.inaxes
   zmx = whichax.get_xlim() #here i get the xlim of the x-axis of the ax that i am in
   move_x = 2 #here when i press 'a' or 'd' i change its xlim by move_x
   print('ok1')
   if event.key == 'd':
       whichax.set_xlim(zmx[0]+move_x,zmx[1]+move_x)
       plt.draw()
       print('ok2')
        
   elif event.key == 'a':
       whichax.set_xlim(zmx[0]-move_x,zmx[1]-move_x)
       plt.draw()
```

And the thing is that i print the values start, ok1, ok2 and they are printed immideately. However the xaxis is changing too slowly. Any ideas to make it faster??

Comment: blitting may help you? https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html?highlight=blitting I think you're currently redrawing all three axes for every key press, instead of just one

Comment: also in general when making applicaitons you should probably stay away from `plt.__` as if the user ever makes a new plot things will get messed up. Instead do `fig.canvas.draw()`

Comment: well even if i use `fig.canvas.draw()` still it is very slow and it takes almost 2 seconds to apply the change. How can i redraw just on one axes?

Comment: see the link about blitting. the second comment was a more general thing, but doesn't impact performance.